# bootstrap 4 navbar - content jumps below brand on collapse

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a double navbar with latest boot4 (alpha6).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrERBP

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light navbar-inverse bg-faded" style="background-color: #000000">

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right navina" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

<!-- <div class="navbar-header"> -->
    <a class="navbar-brand navina" href="/">
        <img src="/images/logow.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav navina hidden-lg-up float-right">
        <img src="/images/search.png">
    </ul>
<!-- </div> -->
    <!-- <div  id="navbarNavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse"> -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav navina hidden-md-down">
        <li class="nav-item navina">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/kosik/">
            <img src="/images/kosik.png" class="img-rounded" aria-hidden="true" style="height:25px; width:25px"> Košík
            <span class="badge"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown navina">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">  <img src="/images/pouz.png" class="img-circle" style="height:25px; width:25px"><span class="caret"></span>
          Používateľ
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu my-2 my-lg-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" align="right">
            {{# if login}}
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user/userprofile">Tvoj účet</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user/logout">Odhlásiť</a>
          {{ else }}
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user/login">Prihlás sa</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user/signup"> Zaregistrovať </a>
          {{/if}}
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- </div> -->
</nav>
```

With medium or smaller viewports, I want the lower navbar to collapse into a right aligned burger menu on the upper navbar.
The user and shopping cart icon along with a search icon are meant to be to the left of this burger menu.

But on collapse the new icons jump below the brand.
Any element added onto the navbar does...

I've spent nearly 3 days at this and several different approaches failed, including adding other `<button>`s (which stack on top of themselves) or floating/margins.

If I place the `<div>`s before the `<brand>` everything stacks above the Brand after collapse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the search icon with the other links on the right and use `ml-auto` to align right..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light navbar-inverse bg-faded" style="background-color: #000000">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right navina" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand navina" href="/">
        <img src="/images/logow.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav hidden-md-down ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link"><img src="/images/search.png" alt="search"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/kosik/">
                <img src="/images/kosik.png" class="img-rounded" aria-hidden="true" style="height:25px; width:25px"> Košík
                <span class="badge"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <img src="/images/pouz.png" class="img-circle" style="height:25px; width:25px"><span class="caret"></span> Používateľ
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu my-2 my-lg-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" align="right">
                {{# if login}}
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user/userprofile">Tvoj účet</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user/logout">Odhlásiť</a> {{ else }}
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user/login">Prihlás sa</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user/signup"> Zaregistrovať </a> {{/if}}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/ztTrZaszBU

***EDIT***

I think I understand that you want the extra links *always* to the left of the toggler. In that case you'd have to force the `navbar-nav` to remain horizontal using the flexbox utils and margins to space it way from the toggler..

`<ul class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap ml-auto mr-sm-5 mr-md-5 mr-lg-0">..</ul>`

[Codeply updated](http://www.codeply.com/go/ztTrZaszBU)

Comment: Big thanks.

I cannot open the codeply link for some reason - it redirects me to a loding screen that never finishes. 

At any rate - in the Edit you understood perfectly - I've tried the solution you describe but, although to the left of the toggler after collapse the links are still on another line (below the navbar and toggler).

Comment: so I added `flex-row` and `flex-nowrap` to the `<nav>` that contains the entire navbar and it solved the problem! thanks!